# Help Google to identify my site as a "web application"

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, rich-snippets

I have a web application, and I want Google to identify it as a "web application". I've had a look at [Rich Snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1645432?hl=en), but there is just an option to "software application" which refers to a desktop application and not web application.
Any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try schema.org metadata for [WebApplication](http://schema.org/WebApplication).
It looks like that.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebApplication">
  <h1 itemprop="name">YOUR_APP_NAME</h1>
  <meta itemprop="about" content="short_info_about_your_app" />
  <meta itemprop="browserRequirements" content="requires FileAPI support" />
  ...
</body>
```